# AWS Device Farm error : Unknown command, all the mobile commands except scroll have been removed

Tags: testng, appium-ios, aws-device-farm

I've a sample test suite as follows :

```
@Test(groups="swipeTest")
public void swipeTest() {
WebElement wl = driver.findElementByName("Video");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "right");
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) wl).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
```

I'm running this test suite with Appium (1.6.4) and TestNg and observe that it runs fine in local simulator. But whereas the same piece of code doesn't work in AWS Device Farm.

```
swipeTest failed: Unknown command, all the mobile commands except scroll 
have been removed. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace 
information) Command duration or timeout: 215 milliseconds Build info: 
version: '3.2.0', revision: '8c03df6b79', time: '2017-02-23 10:51:31 +0000' 
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-53-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_65' 
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver Capabilities 
[{app=com.sears.relay, networkConnectionEnabled=false, 
databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=546f99bb46f19bd77d35316105eda6af056611ae, 
platform=MAC, platformVersion=10.0.2, webStorageEnabled=false, 
locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=, takesScreenshot=true, 
javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=iOS, 
udid=546f99bb46f19bd77d35316105eda6af056611ae}] Session ID: 5360d97b-4fa9-
440e-af0a-5b9b55acf87d
```

For running on AWS Device Farm, instead of IOSDriver, I've initialized RemoteWebDriver and followed the process outlined in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/test-ios-apps-on-aws-device-farm-using-appium-part-1-prerequisities-environment-set-up-and-test-creation/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.
There are few noteworthy things that are most likely causing this issue:

1. In the log snippet you posted we can still see the IOSDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver.
2. The capability javascriptEnabled = true also shows up in the log.
3. You are actually trying to run Javascript Appium from your code.
4. Groups annotation is being used on test level.

On Device Farm Javascript appium and groups annotation are not supported. 
Hope this helps.